# When I run make with -git submodule init command I get "Not a git repository "

Tags: git, makefile, gnu, git-submodules, init

When I run make and the makefile attempts to execute a `-git` submodule `init` command I receive `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Do you have any more details? (OS, git version, Makefile content or project URL where we can have a look?)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error of my ways. I originally had downloaded the repository instead of cloning it from a linux terminal command line. Now that I've cloned it from the linux terminal command line via git -clone .git , the submodule inits are successful. Thanks everyone for your consideration.